# Server and Client Secure Identification without SSL

Tags: c#, authentication, ssl, encryption

I'm currently developing a C# application that communicates between a client and server using TCP/IP. After connecting I'm swapping session based RSA public keys to then pass a session based AES symmetrical key. This all works fine and means I have a secure channel to communicate on.

The trouble now is that I need to ensure that the server and client are both the ones I wish to communicate with. Before anyone suggests SSL/TLS: I'm not connected to the Internet to allow the use of a root CA.

Would it be valid, that after establishing a secure channel between the client and server that I provide a simple challenge-response method? For example, if the client sends an identifier (GUID?) the server compares this value to known clients and accepts or rejects it, and the same is repeated in the opposite direction. As the data is encrypted and the encryption is session based is this a valid method of verification?

I understand that the storage of these identifiers is the weak point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Before anyone suggests SSL/TLS: I'm not connected to the Internet to allow the use of a root CA.

Before you are re-inventing the wheel: you don't need root CA with SSL/TLS but can simply use self-signed certificates with [key pinning](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Certificate_and_Public_Key_Pinning). Public root CAs are only usually used because it scales much better to provide only few common CAs instead of exchanging all self-signed certificates (or their fingerprint) to all peers of the communication.

Apart from that it looks like you proposal assumes a secure connection already to check credentials which you then will use to verify that the connection is really secure. Or in short: to provide a secure connection you need a secure connection first.

Comment: I had avoided the whole SSL because I thought there would be hassle with self-signed certificates. The key pinning resolves this completely.